# Send server side generated PDF to the browser

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an AJAX call that calls a static WebMethod on the Server side.
The Server side Method returns a MemoryStream containing the byte stream of the PDF file.
How can I then use this PDF byte stream on the client side in the success method of the AJAX call, to somehow trigger the PDF file download. 
I would also don't what to do a full postback of the page.

I've used this as reference: http://forums.asp.net/t/1377154.aspx?Download+from+Javascript
But I would like to have a full example achieving this.

```
function generatePDF(param1, param2, param3) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Page.aspx/GeneratePDF',
        data: '{ "param1" : "' + param1+ '", "param2" : "' + param2+ '", "param3" : "' + param3+ '" }',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (pdf) {

            //from here somehow, download the generated PDF file
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can you try from code behind. and I have added example.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally done this, but the first thing I would try would be:

On the server side dynamically build the appropriate HTML document and CSS
Use phantomJS to render that document
Tell phantomJS to convert that document to PDF, saved in a temp file
Send the PDF back as the HTTP response by writing the temp PDF file to the response body
Delete the temp file
If you are struggling with content-type, content-disposition, etc, you shouldn't have to worry about that if you have a valid pdf file on disk and just write that data to the HTTP response. With the right headers, you should be able to ask the browser to either display the PDF or treat it as a file to be saved as a download.

Answer (score 0):

Here I would suggest you to use

```
Window.open('~/path/name.pdf');
```

using this you can display the pdf on browser and can save and print from browser.

Comment: I don't want to keep the file on the server, since it might remain an orphan file. I just want to send a byte stream from the server side to the browser and then use that byte stream to pop up the download file window.

Comment: ok, but again I would suggest you to not using ajax call for this operation, use window.open                                          Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
            Response.OutputStream.Flush();
            Response.OutputStream.Close();

Comment: Thanks, do you have a full example for this?

Answer (score 0):

try this,
Selected bytes from database and give to content.

```
byte[] content = "Select Your Bytes From Database";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = false;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=" + fileName);
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
//Write the file content directly to the HTTP content output stream.
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(content);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Comment: I cannot use this in the WebMethod call.

Comment: ok. but you can also use on server side event.
from your client side you can call your server side event than its working.